# Move specific rarely used or non-performance critical files off SSD

Tags: windows-7, windows, ssd, disk-space

I was trying to make some more space on an SSD boot drive today since it is getting very tight for space with C:\Windows stuff and applications that seem to insist on putting stuff on the system drive. The system has 1TB of HDD space as well.

Is it possible to move rarely used or non-performance critical files onto the SSD? Examples would be many of the system fonts (700MB), Windows\Installer files (20GB), certain things in the user AppData & and system ProgramData (e.g. do the F1 games really need 2GB replay files on an SSD, as long as the HDD can read/write at the required speed), etc, and some stuff that seems to demand C:\Program Files.

I was thinking perhaps some way to keep the directory structure on the SSD (well I guess it has to), but have the filesystem point to the HDD for the actual file contents (symbolic link?).

Answer (score -2):

Try these:

http://www.gabsoftware.com/tips/recover-free-space-in-windows-seven-windows-7-sp1-and-windows-server-2008-r2/

http://www.optimizingpc.com/optimize/deletefiles.html

Comment: Can you copy and paste, or paraphrase links? It helps prevent link rot

Comment: Reducing someone's reputation just because they violate unpublished rules doesn't exactly encourage participation. My answers were valid and to-the-point.

Comment: I also didn't downvote, as I don't know if the information is valid or not (I was on my mobile when I posted that)